# Rewriting RegEx to be used in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have written `(?<=pp_).*(?=')` regex to match what comes after `pp_` in strings like

`['newPage', 'pp_vii', -1]`

My regex works fine in online testers (see [online regex validator](https://regex101.com/r/nC9RJ8/1)) but it won't in Java. My  failing code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=pp_).*(?=')");
String input = "['newPage', 'pp_vii', -1])";
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
boolean match = m.matches(); // false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Regex is fine. The `Matcher.matches()` method only returns true, if the complete String matches the pattern ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches())). You should use `Matcher.find()` instead. That finds the next subsequence that matches the pattern ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find())).

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=pp_).*(?=')");
String input = "['newPage', 'pp_vii', -1])";
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
boolean stringMatches = m.matches(); // false
boolean isThereMatch = m.find(); // true
System.out.println(isThereMatch + " " + stringMatches);
System.out.println(m.group());
```

That prints:

```
true false
vii
```

Comment: That works fine. However, how do I get what was matched? `String s = matcher.group(0)` and `tring pageLabel = matcher.group()` both throws exceptions. I debugged m object and in its int[] groups there are always -1.

Comment: Swap the lines with `find` and `matches`. The matcher has an index, which is at the end of the String after running `matches` so this is causing the exception. You have to call the `group` method after calling `find`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) method check for full string match so instead of that use [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) method which checks for subsequence match. Finally, you can use [`group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()) method to get matched subsequence string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=pp_).*(?=')");
String input = "['newPage', 'pp_vii', -1])";
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
boolean a = m.find(); 

if(a){
    String out = m.group();
    System.out.println("Match : " + out);
}
```